# Compare files size between the source and the target folder in python

Tags: python, windows, compare

I have two folders with the same file name. I will compare the file size between the source folder and the target folder

Source_Folder:

File1

File2

….

FileN

Target_Folder:

File1

File2

….

FileN

I can check the file size by the following code.

```
import os

file_size = os.path.getsize(‘C:\Folder1\folder2\file1.csv’)

print(“File Size is :”, file_size, “bytes”)
```

How can I Compare files size between the source and the target folder in python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

folder1 = os.listdir("YourSourceFolderPath")
file1Size=0

folder2 = os.listdir("YourTargetFolderPath")
file2Size=0

for file in folder1,folder2:

    if(os.path.isfile("YourSourceFolderPath/"+file)):
        file1Size= os.path.getsize("YourSourceFolderPath/"+file)

    if(os.path.isfile("YourTargetFolderPath/"+file)):
        file2Size= os.path.getsize("YourTargetFolderPath/"+file)

    print(file1Size,file2Size)
```

Comment: Hi Firat, Thank you for your code, I will compare :
Source_Folder\File1 with Target_Folder\File1;
Source_Folder\File2 with Target_Folder\File2;
...
Source_Folder\FileN with Target_Folder\FileN

Comment: I editted my answer, I hope it helps you.